# How do you work on your HTML and CSS in PLay! + intellij idea?

Tags: html, css, intellij-idea, playframework, frontend

I am new to playframework for Scala. I am also new to front-end development. I am using Play 2.x. I develop in Intellij Idea

My problems:

1. When working on my html and css to see the result of a simple code change I need to wait until template recompiles (10-12 seconds for my environment).
   I tried opening page with all Play!'s scala tags using browser button in idea, but it doesn't find my css. 
   Please suggest, how can I improve my html+css development experience here?
2. There are many tools to validate quality of your front-end (example: list of tools at http://webdevchecklist.com/ ). Many of these tools require your web app already be available online. How do you solve this issue? Do you always have some online testing environment? Is that the only solution here?
3. Is there some way to teach Intellij Idea to understand Play!'s templates in html editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ad. 1 - do you use tilda for running app? like: `play ~run`? it tries to compile project after changes in files are detected, so it could faster things a little... Anyway for massive FE work just save source code generated by your controller to static file like `public/test.html` so it will be accessible via `localhost:9000/assets/test.html`

Ad. 2 - I doubt if anybody uses remote environment for testing HTML in Play (development problem), use tools which allows for testing offline or by sending files. Eventually front-end issues can be tested with static files + HTTP server. Finally you can just make your local machine accessible from net - check i.e. services like http://dyn.com/ - it will allow you to create dynamic *domain*

Ad. 3 - IntelliJ since ver. 12 has support for Play 2.0+ (*Ultimate Edition* only)